# Calling external APIs having SSO on Azure AD

Tags: iframe, single-sign-on, internet-explorer-11, azure-active-directory, openid

- I have an Intranet authenticating by Azure AD - located at **https://intranet.example.com/** (In details, its Sharepoint Online);
- In some pages, we need dynamic content generated by an rest api - located at **https://api.example.com/** (In details, .NET WebAPI, Owin middleware using OpenId);
- api.example auth by AAD too;
- Both api.example and intranet.example have Windows Azure AD permission granted through admin consent;
- api.example has X-Frame-Options, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and Access-Control-Allow-Origin enabled to https://intranet.example.com/;

## What I need:

Some pages have dynamic content generated by JavaScript logic requesting data from **api.example**;

Users will authenticate in *intranet.example* and *api.example* must have Single Sign On behaviour.

**Avoiding any type of prompt or authorize request is a MUST**, since all of that must be transparent to the final user;

## What I tried:

I tried to simply put an IFrame inside intranet.example pointing to app.example and it works both on Chrome/Firefox. But, IE11 doesnt allow it, since my app redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ that responds with **X-FRAME-OPTIONS** set to **DENY**.

## Example:

- User log in Google Account, access https://mail.google.com/ and have hangouts messages up and running with no prompt or authorize request or something else, totally transparent.
- User log in Microsoft Personal Account, access https://onedrive.live.com/ and have Skype messages up and running with no prompt or authorize request or something else, totally transparent.

Note1: It must works outside our domain. So, setting Intranet/Trusted Site Zone is not a option.
Note2: The more decoupled from Sharepoint, the better.
Note3: I tried this aproach [PnP Webcast - Calling external APIs securely from SharePoint Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDjKRfHA1nw).

Comment: You need to acquire the corresponding token to call the web API which protect by Azure AD. Is [this code sample[(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) helpful? Please feel free to let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: @FeiXue Thanks for your response. I think it will not solve my problem as soon my intranet.example will have to redirect to microsoft login page to get the access token. It will require an popup to be opened and it means user will have to click some button or putting intranet.example into intranet zone ):

Comment: If you were implement the SSO via the OpenID connect, it will not prompt the login page when the users already sign-in. The only things that you need to do in the web app is acquire the token for the corresponding resource using `AuthorizationCodeReceived` as the code sample demonstrates.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheusCosta - does this problem only affects IE11? What about other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend re-posting your question in [SharePoint Stack
   Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).
2. [AadHttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient) might be a better option, but it's in preview right now and 'not supported in production tenants'.  It also requires the new SharePoint Admin Center which is only available for first release tenants.

[image]

Also, I found these to be better AadHttpClient tutorials than the existing MS documentation:

- https://www.spdavid.com/consume-a-secured-azurefunction-using/
- https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1378